# i want to select all nodes except all decendents of perticular node

Tags: html, css

i am unable to use somthing like this

i.e. i want to select all nodes except all decendents of `.myPaperContainer`

```
*:not(.myPaperContainer *){}
```

Is there any other way of doing this in css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly.

```
* { /* apply some styles */ }
.myPaperContainer * { /* revert above styles to initial values */ }
```

That's about the closest you can get to what you're trying to do.

Comment: what if i assign height=0 in *{} then how should i be able revert back height of .myPaperContainer to its origonal value without using jquery. where heights are in percent

Comment: that´s right. You can only define a style for an element and then with classes the special ones. Just give the one you dont want do enable the style another class than the other one you want to. Or another possibility would be that you set all your styles with javascript. Then you can do exact what you are been aksing for. But it´s impossible to do it that way with only using css.

Comment: so i end up grouping my classes with one common name and i used that class in :not() statement. so till date JANUARY 2014 you are right there is no direct way of doing it through css.